# ResourceNotFound Error with Microsoft Graph API for Excel

Tags: excel, office365api

Are access tokens returned from Microsoft's [v2 authentication endpoint](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/converged_auth) valid for accessing the Excel REST API?

I receive an access token when going through the OAuth flow, and can access OneDrive endpoints such as:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive`

But if I try to access an Excel endpoint such as:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/`

... I get 404 ResourceNotFound error

Note that I've registered for my Client ID via the [Microsoft app registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v2.0 endpoint could works well for this API when I test with the work account. And I also reproduced this issue when I use the personal account.

Comment: Thank you. I was testing with a personal account.